# using an alias or property in place of a field in django

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-1.5, django-models

I have created a custom user class in django 1.5, inheriting AbstractBaseUser. The class has a field 'email' which is the unique ID. However, I'm using an externally developed app which is expecting the User class to have a field `username` for use in a `get()`. I would prefer not to add an extra unnecessary field to my user class, and would like to return the email address to this app when it asks for the username. I have attempted to do this using a property in my user class:

```
@property
def username(self):
    return self.email
```

But I continue to get `FieldError ... Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field`

I'm guessing this has to do with database lookups. Is there another way to acheive this? Perhaps a way to specify a fieldname alias?

Answer (score 0):

`get()` invokes `QuerySet.filter()`, creating property does not have an effect on `QuerySet`, it only works when access an `user` instance's attribute `user.username`.

You can do this by creating custom queryset:

```
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def __getattr__(self, attr, *args):
        try:
            return getattr(self.__class__, attr, *args)
        except AttributeError:
            return getattr(self.get_query_set(), attr, *args)

    def get_query_set(self):
        return MyQuerySet(self.model)

class MyQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'username' in kwargs:
            kwargs.update({'email': kwargs.pop('username')})
        return super(MyQuerySet, self).filter(*args, **kwargs)

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = ...

    objects = MyUserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```